# ASP.Net MVC4 beta - no await keyword support in HttpClient?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, async-await

Does the `HttpClient` class in the MVC4 beta not support the `await` keyword? I have have had the async CTP installed for a while now, but also now have the MVC4 beta and the compiler tells me that `HttpClient` methods are not awaitable, despite the various code samples I see on the web that suggest otherwise. What am I missing?

**EDIT**

I'm talking about any of the *Async() methods. e.g. `await client.PutAsync(...);`

Comment: Could you post your exact code (at least the whole method), along with the exact message the compiler gives you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The await-able interface changed a little with the beta, so if you can use VS11 instead (and the recent targeting pack if the project is downlevel (.NET 4, SL 5)) then you should be fine. The older async CTP compiler doesn't know of the change. :)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler message is confusing. You must add AsyncCtpLibrary.dll to your project. Quickly done with NuGet package AsyncAwaitCTP.